# Agfx and caliburn.micro example

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-7.1, caliburn.micro, agfx

I am currently using caliburn.micro in my WP7 project and I am quite happy with it. My application is very data-heavy, so I took a look at Agfx (http://agfx.codeplex.com), seems it can save me a lot of time on data requesting and caching.

But the problem here is that agfx also provide a base view model, while I've already had one which inherits Screen of caliburn.micro. Of course I can encapsulate a new view model base which inherits ModelItemBase from agfx, and implements IScreen. But I kinda don't like this, is there any better soultion or best practice you can share with me about how to integrate the 2 great frameworks?

Best Regards,

-Peng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am actually using AgFx with another UI framework which has its own `ViewModelBase`. My own understanding is, the `ModelItemBase` that's provided by AgFx is a model base rather than a viewmodel base. It basically takes care of the data.

My viewmodel which inherits from my `ViewModelBase`, does a lot more stuff like Tombstoning, application bar bindings, etc. It's designed for displaying the data on the view.

I think it fits in mvvm and works out really well. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I got what you mean, but ModelItemBase inherits from INotifyPropertyChange, does that mean it is designed for VM? and doing so might blur the boundary of domain models and VMs, right?

Comment: Nope, INotifyPropertyChanged is not UI specific, what if a property his changed in the model? In this case you need to have it on your model to notify your vm about this change.

Comment: Xin, are you using it with MVVM Light? If so, could you give a small overview on how you combine it with Agfx?

Comment: @Depechie Sorry I am using Jeremy Likness' UltraLight Mvvm framework http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jlikness/archive/2011/02/25/building-a-windows-phone-7-application-with-ultralight-mvvm.aspx not sure about MvvmLight though. :(

Comment: Xin any way I could contact you for a bit more detail on your implementation? I'm Depechie on twitter...